# List a directory, including subdirectories, with file count and cumulative size

Tags: command-line, ls, disk-usage

Is there a way to list out the content of a directory including subdirectories with a file count and cumulative size?

I would like to see:

- Number of directories
- Number of sub directories
- number of files
- cumulative size

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Option to which program? What exactly do you mean by _cumulative_ size? This type of question is always better with an example.

Comment: if the folder contain 10 files  then i need cumulative size of the files.

Comment: Cumulative or total? Cumulative means if A=1, B=2 and C=4, you will get `A=1, AB=3, ABC=7`. I think you want the number of subdirectories, the number of files, and the size of each subdirectory plus the size of the parent directory. Is that correct? Please consider adding an example so we can understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this will give you want you want:

```
find /path/to/target -type d | while IFS= read -r dir; do 
  echo -ne "$dir\tsize: $(du -sh "$dir" | cut -f 1)" 
  echo -ne "\tsubdirs: $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l)"
  echo -e "\tfiles: $(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l )";
done  | tac
```

If you run this on `/boot` for example, you get output like this:

```
/boot/burg/themes/sora_extended size: 8.0K  subdirs: 0  files: 1
/boot/burg/themes/radiance/images   size: 196K  subdirs: 0  files: 48
/boot/burg/themes/radiance  size: 772K  subdirs: 1  files: 53
/boot/burg/themes/winter    size: 808K  subdirs: 0  files: 35
/boot/burg/themes/icons size: 712K  subdirs: 0  files: 76
/boot/burg/themes   size: 8.9M  subdirs: 26 files: 440
/boot/burg/fonts    size: 7.1M  subdirs: 0  files: 74
/boot/burg  size: 20M   subdirs: 29 files: 733
/boot/grub/locale   size: 652K  subdirs: 0  files: 17
/boot/grub  size: 4.6M  subdirs: 1  files: 224
/boot/extlinux/themes/debian-wheezy/extlinux    size: 732K  subdirs: 0  files: 11
/boot/extlinux/themes/debian-wheezy size: 1.5M  subdirs: 1  files: 22
/boot/extlinux/themes   size: 1.5M  subdirs: 2  files: 22
/boot/extlinux  size: 1.6M  subdirs: 3  files: 28
/boot/  size: 122M  subdirs: 36 files: 1004
```

To have easy access to this command, you could turn it into a function. Add these lines to your shell's initialization file (`~/.bashrc` for bash):

```
dirsize(){
    find "$1" -type d | while IFS= read -r dir; do 
    echo -ne "$dir\tsize: $(du -sh "$dir"| cut -f 1)" 
    echo -ne "\tsubdirs: $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l)"
    echo -e "\tfiles: $(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l )";
    done  | tac
}
```

You can now run it as `dirsize /path/`.

---

### Explanation

The function above has 5 major parts:

1. `find /path/to/target -type d | while IFS= read -r dir; do ... ; done` : This will find all directories under `/path/to/target` and process each of them by setting the variable `dir` to their name. The `IFS=` ensures this won't break on directories with spaces in their names.
2. `echo -ne "$dir\tsize: $(du -sh "$dir" | cut -f 1)"` : This uses the command `du` to get the directory's size and `cut` to print only the first field of `du`.
3. `echo -ne "\tsubdirs: $(find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l)"` : This find command looks for subdirectories of `$dir`. The `type -d` ensures we only find directories, no files and the `-mindepth` makes sure we do not count the current directory, `.`.
4. `echo -e "\tfiles: $(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)";` : This one looks for files (`-type f`) that are *directly* (`-maxdepth 1`) under `$dir`. It will not count files that are in subdirectories of `$d`.
5. `| tac` :  Finally, the whole thing is passed through [`tac`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tac) which simply reverses the order in which lines are printed. This means that the total size of the target directory will be shown as the last line. If that is not what you want, simply delete `| tac`.

Comment: Thanks a lot terdon, this is one i want exactly. thanks once again.